# How to apply a filter condition in a entity including related entity

Tags: entity-framework-6

How would the conversion of this SQL query to LinqToEntity Syntax using Method Syntax?

```
SELECT  Recurso.IdRecurso, Recurso.Codigo, 
        Recurso.Titulo, Recurso.Descripcion
FROM    Recurso INNER JOIN
        RecursoUsuario ON Recurso.IdRecurso = RecursoUsuario.IdRecurso
WHERE   (RecursoUsuario.IdUsuario = 1)
```

I test next, but error in .Where(x => x.RecursoUsuario.**IdUsuario** == idUsuario)

```
 public List<Recurso> RecursosPorUsuario(int idUsuario)
        {
            List<Recurso> ru = 
                bd.Recurso.Include("RecursoUsuario")
                .Where(x => x.RecursoUsuario.IdUsuario == idUsuario);

            return ru;
        }
```

Could you helme please?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ Query IncludeFilter feature allow filtering related entities.

```
public List<Recurso> RecursosPorUsuario(int idUsuario)
{
    List<Recurso> ru = bd.Recurso
                         .IncludeFilter(x => x.RecursoUsuario
                                              .Where(x => x.RecursoUsuario.IdUsuario == idUsuario))
                         .ToList();

    return ru;
}
```

Wiki: [EF+ Query IncludeFilter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

**Solution #2**

Another technique is by using projection (which is what my library do under the hood)

```
public List<Recurso> RecursosPorUsuario(int idUsuario)
{
    List<Recurso> ru = bd.Recurso
                         .Select(x = new {
                            Recurso = x,
                            RecursoUsuarios = x.RecursoUsuario.
                                               .Where(x => x.RecursoUsuario.IdUsuario == idUsuario)
                         })
                         .ToList()
                         .Select(x => x.Recurso)
                         .ToList();

    return ru;
}
```